# Earliest use of "book," the slang verb meaning "to leave quickly"

Tags: etymology, slang, british-english

"Book," the slang verb meaning to leave quickly--has anyone found it used prior to the 1840s?  I found it used in chapter 143 of Varney the Vampire: "[I]f the old watchman comes round, we may have to book it . . . "

Also, does anyone know if book is a regional expression?  I first heard it in the mid-1970s in rural central Alabama along among the students when I was in sixth grade.

Comment: Is this two questions? If so, please only ask one at a time, so people can find info easier and the answers don't get too long...

Comment: The earlier entry was incomplete and in error.  It was also locked.  I had new information.  I know the meaning of the word.  I was wanting to find out if anyone had found an even earlier occurrence of it.  If you want to unlock the previous thread, I'll be happy to move it there.

Comment: As requested, I took out the extraneous reference to another expression to simplify things.